# Angular HTML Linter

Tags: angular, static-analysis

I would like to introduce a code style into my team. I'm aware about Codelyzer for Angular, but seems like it lints typescript code only (both .html and .ts). It's OK, but I want to format HTML using Angular Style Guide. For example, for pipes:

What my team has:

```
{{test | translate:{a: b} }}
{{test|translate:{a: b} }}
{{test | translate: {a: b} }}
{{test|translate: {a:b} }}
...
```

What I want:

```
{{test | translate:{a: b} }}
```

I would also great if I could set the rule (or some kind of auto-fixing) for sorting Angular attributes. For example, I like to put inputs first, then outputs, then ordinary directives, then structural directives:

Before:

```
<div (click)="test($event)" appDirective *ngIf="qwe" [a]="1"></div>
```

After:

```
<div [a]="1"
     (click)="test($event)"
     appDirective
     *ngIf="qwe">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try https://prettier.io/ ? Its good to implement team standards.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I could not find any guides about Angular HTML formatting (it does not resolve examples above).

Comment: Also interested in a formatter for Angular Templates. Prettier has issues with angular, at least if you use angulars i18n  solution https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8338 Here a related angular entry:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13114